# Best way to get Cara Dune minifig

Tags: minifigures

With so many Mandalorian sets being retired this year and the controversy around the actress, I don't want to miss out on the Cara Dune minifig.

What sets is this minifig available in and which is the best value for money?

Comment: When I answered the question, it asked about "what ways" to get the minifig. Now it has been edited to read "What sets is this minifig.. in" which is NOT the same.

Comment: @RSchulz I did the edit thinking it wouldn't change the meaning of the question significantly. I still consider your answer relevant, though you're of course free to restore the original wording if you feel that version would fit your answer better.

Answer (score 3):

[Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw1058) has lots of them for sale - depending on how close to you one of the sellers is (to cut down on shipping cost, or even to pick up in person if that's allowed) you might not be able to beat that price anywhere.

If you need 700 of them, there's one [seller](https://store.bricklink.com/MagicMagnus?itemID=258618300#/shop?o=%7B%22itemID%22:180433,%22showHomeItems%22:0%7D) that claims to have that, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to buy Cara Dune in a set you can buy the [AT-ST Raider 75254](https://rebrickable.com/sets/75254-1/at-st-raider/) from 2019. The only other set she is available in is [75315 Imperial Light Cruiser](https://rebrickable.com/sets/75315-1/imperial-light-cruiser/), which is significantly more expensive.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Thanks for your willingness to share you knowledge with our community. I updated your answer to include a link to the set you mentioned and expanded it to include the only other set I'm aware of with this minifig.

Answer (score 0):

Just buy the [AT-ST with Cara Dune (75254)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/75254-1/at-st-raider/) in it. Alternatively you could look on Bricklink (as RSchulz sugggested) or eBay.com.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Thanks for sharing. It's worth noting that this set is no longer sold on LEGO.com in most markets and will likely be disappearing from retailers as their stock is sold making it hard to find and/or expensive in some locations.